# get new data from api

Tags: javascript, json, api

**Hello I'm trying to get new data from API (filtering data with JSON file)
I want to filter data from API and filter with JSON file and get what new
I tried**

```
    const jsnf = JSON.stringify(fs.readFileSync("./data.json", "utf8"));
    const res = await axios.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/new")
    const data1 = res.data.data.items;
    const data2 = JSON.stringify(data1)
    const data3 = JSON.stringify(Object.values(data1), null, 2)
```

**I also tried console.log data3 (data from JSON file) and got:**
[result for data3 (console.log(data3) )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaGqD.png)

**Also i did console.log for data1 (data from api) and got:**
[result for data1 (console.log(data1) )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clFqm.png)

**[ if I do:**

```
console.log(data1.filter((x) => jsnf.includes(x)))
```

**I will get nothing `[]` ]**

> **Please if you know how to make [ console.log(jsnf == data1) \\true**

****`OR`****

> **[ console.log(data1.filter((x) => jsnf.includes(x))) ] \\x = new items from api  ] please let me know how, thanks!**

Comment: What data is there in your jsnf variable?

Comment: And also you are doing stringify... You must do JSON.parse() instead so that Javascript  function can be  used

Comment: What's the content of `jsnf`? `includes` basically compares with `===` , which most certainly will fail for your objects, because for objects, `===` returns true only if they point to the same reference. Which obviously is not the case as one is read from a local file and the other returned from an API.

Comment: please add your json objects and expected output so that can be easy to understand what actually you want

Comment: Can you create one codepen.io example or also provide your data jsnf hard coded for now :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are reading file `data.json` from your local device and doing `JSON.stringify` on the returned file.

```
 const jsnf = JSON.stringify(fs.readFileSync("./data.json", "utf8"));
```

Know that it is a `string` now and if you without using `JSON.parse(jsnf)` start using your filter logic.

```
console.log(data1.filter((x) => jsnf.includes(x)));
```

Know that this will not work as expected.

Also until and unless we know what data is in `jsnf` we cannot we sure about your logic to filter things.

Comment: Seems like the `stringify` is just for output purposes. OP wants to execute `filter()` on `data1` which (eventually) is an array returned from a rest call

Comment: Is it? Thanks for this update .Let me modify my answer or delete it if it is of now help to anyone :)

Comment: Have just updated my answer, so that it makes more sense... Actually OP hasn't been quite expressive in his/her question :)